# clone a div with slide Down effect after some scroll

Tags: jquery

> clone a Div with slide Down effect, for example when i scroll then
>   add a clone of a div with slide down effect,any help should be
>   appreciated

```
      if (scroll >= 280) {
       $(function(){
  var $button = $('.hd').clone();
  $('.ap').html($button);
});
```

> when i scroll it will inserted multiple times i want only once with slide down Effect

[js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cacp1r36/5/)

Comment: make a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Add some flag to check if the div is inserted once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use boolean for that

```
var inserated = false
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 180) {
        $('.hd').each(function() {
            if(inserated == false){
                var $button = $('.hd').clone();
                $('.ap').html($button);
                inserated = true;
            }
        });
    }else{

    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/cacp1r36/10/)

and if you just have this piece of code with one .hd class  you can just use

```
var inserated = false
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 180 && inserated == false) {
        var $button = $('.hd').clone();
        $('.ap').html($button);
        inserated = true;
    }else{

    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/cacp1r36/9/)

Comment: @rahul  you welcome .. I just updated my answer with another case you can check it if you need .. Good Luck :)